# iAd Banner swift , after i added iAd the game started crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, debugging, iad

i developed this game , and it works fine like i want it to do , but after i added the iAd banner , when i start the game it would run normally for like 10 sec. and the it zoom in and make every thing very large and then it would give me this error :

```
Shapes#2[75422:7643415] [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=1 "Service session terminated." UserInfo=0x7fdb09f5b1e0 {ADInternalErrorCode=1002, NSLocalizedDescription=Service session terminated.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your didFailToReceiveAdWithError function. You can copy and paste this code in, just make sure you iAd banner matches what is in your project:

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error failed to load. Probably due to network connection.")
    self.adBannerView.hidden = true//hide the banner
}
```

The problem is probably the iAd banner cannot load and you don't have the didFailToReceiveAdWithError function which runs when the banner can't load. If the banner doesn't load, and there's no function to handle this, the compiler will complain. 
P.S. You may want to insert this function too. This one is the opposite of didFailToReceiveAdWithError, it runs when the banner can load.

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    println("Banner did load.")
    self.adBannerView.hidden = false//show banner
}
```

You can find more info about iAd [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/)

Comment: i added the function but still sometimes it crashes and gives the same error , and sometimes the game runs normally

Comment: Based on my experience with iAd, the simulator would mess up then the game would always run fine on an actual device. Are you testing in a simulator or a device? @NaiemSalib

Comment: Simulator , i don't have a developers account yet

Comment: Ok, that may be your problem. It may not be a problem with the code but instead with the simulator or Xcode if you're on the beta. Betas are always glitchy. @NaiemSalib Happy coding